# Excel 2010 VBA: .Names.Add does not work after .Hyperlinks.Add

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have run into a problem in Excel 2010 VBA on Windows 7 64-bit version which I have not been able to solve. The issue can easily be recreated by pasting the code below in a module in a new workbook and run it.

What I want to do is to loop through a number of sheets and add a defined name and a hyperlink on each sheet.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim defName As String
    For i = 1 To 2
        Set ws = Sheets(i)
        defName = "Name_" & ws.Name
        ws.Names.Add Name:=defName, RefersToR1C1:="=OFFSET(Sheet3!R1C1,0,0,1)"
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("A1"), _
             Address:="", SubAddress:="=Sheet3!A1"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Running the code gives the following error on the second iteration, on the ws.Names.Add call: Run-time error '1004: The formula you typed contains an error.

Doing any of the following makes the error disappear:

- Change the for iteration to "i = 1 To 1" or "i = 2 To 2"
- Put a debug breakpoint inside the for loop and pressing F5 when it has stopped
- Change the cell reference to 
  `ws.Names.Add Name:=defName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet3!R1C1"`, i.e. removing the OFFSET command

Adding `DoEvents` to the first line of the for loop or setting `Application.EnableEvents = False` does not solve the problem.

Does anyone know the cause of this error or how to get around it? I am thankful for any help.

Edit: The issue occurs no matter what the hyperlink links to. Changing the hyperlink to the following does not solve the issue

`ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("A1"), Address:="http://www.google.com"`

Edit2: Managed to recreate the issue with an even simpler code:

```
Sub Test()
    With Sheets(1)
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="http://www.google.com"
        .Names.Add Name:="myDefName", RefersToR1C1:="=OFFSET(Sheet1!R1C1,0,0,1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't error for me in Excel 2010 if I just copy - paste an run...

Comment: I tried doing it again after reading your comment. New blank workbook -> Alt+F11 -> New Module -> Paste and run the code. I still got the error. I am running Windows 7 x64, if that could matter.

Comment: try changing `for i = 1 to 2` to `for i = 1 to sheets.count-1` and make sure `Sheet3` actually exists when you start a new workbook. I think there is only 1 sheet by default on windows 8

Comment: No, still not working... There are three sheets and it does not matter to which sheet I link, the same issue still appears.

Comment: I am running Excel 2010 on Windows 7 x64, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the named range before re-creating it? You could be experiencing some sort of conflict with trying to create a name that already exists.

Comment: Both of your code snippets run without error for me in Excel 2010 on 64bit Win 7.

Comment: Are your sheets called 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3' etc.? The code runs fine for me - the only issue I can see would be that your formulas wouldn't work if the sheets were named something other than the default.

Comment: I asked two colleagues to run the code and they both get the same error. Is it possible that it is computer specific, we are all running HP Probook 6450b?

Comment: citizenkong: Yes, they are named properly. And it works if I put a debug breakpoint between the hyperlink.add and names.add commands.

Comment: Tested with another HP model, still the error occurs. I have no other brands available.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by separating the for loops into two loops, one for the .names.add calls and one for the  hyperlinks.add calls. This way all the names get defined before the first hyperlink is created.

Sorry if it is not correct of me to post this as an answer.